# request from servlet but i dont get the respond from angularjs

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, jakarta-ee, servlets

```
if(request.getParameter("btnadd")!=null) {

            int eId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("eId")); 

            String datepicker = request.getParameter("datepicker");

            String name = request.getParameter("name");

            String cmp = request.getParameter("cmp");

            String insertRecord = dataBaseEngine.insertDepartment(eId, datepicker, name, cmp);   

            String  btnadd = String.valueOf(insertRecord);

            response.setContentType("application/json");

            out.print("{\"btnadd\" : \"" + btnadd + "\"}");

            out.flush();

            out.close();

            request.getRequestDispatcher("").forward(request, response);
            response.sendRedirect("");
        }
```

AngularJs code

```
     $scope.btnadd = function() {
         $.ajax({
            url: 'Srvlet',
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                    eId: $scope.newcontact.eId,
                    datepicker: $scope.newcontact.datepicker,
                    name: $scope.newcontact.name, 
                    cmp: $scope.newcontact.cmp
                },
             success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                 console.log(data);
                 $scope.$apply(function(){
                     $scope.newcontact.btnadd = data.btnadd;
                 });
             },
             error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                 console.log('Error : ' + jqXHR.responseText);
             }
        });  

    };
```

Comment: Hi everyone ! i came across a issue where i am spending like more than one week to fix the conflict, currently i can pass record to the mysql database, and and once i check the respond from Google chrome javascript console view (CTRL + SHIFT + I) the i just saw Error: depicts at once and goes to invisible state, and from other hand i am receiving an error message stating that  throw Error('No module: ' + name); i got no idea how to fix it, expecting form some guidelines lines in order to fix this issue

Comment: You should put your question **in** your question, not as a comment on it.

Comment: @tinyGeek It sounds like you have an angular error that doesnt have much to do with java. You should look up the angular error and find out what it means. Angular is awesome and will sometimes have links directly to the error on their website in your js console.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you using jquery.ajax instead of the Angular $http service?

Comment: Thanks a lot for kind feedback based on my post i have made and apologize for posting my question has a comment due to certain adjustment i have to follow . Many thanks to azurefrog, ns47731 and Kenneth Baltrinic ,